# How can I make this bash code remove the decimal places?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}'
```

I want to remove the decimal places from this output.

Comment: You don't need grep when you're using awk and it's not clear what you mean by "remove the decimals". Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask].

Comment: `awk '/MemFree/{f=$2};/MemTotal/{t=$2};END{printf("%0.02f%% Free mem\n",100*(f/t))}' /proc/meminfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}' | cut -d. -f1
```

or

```sh
free | grep Mem | awk '{print int($4/$2 * 100.0)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple observations:

1. No need for using `grep` as `awk` can handle that
2. Use `printf` instead of `print` to control the precision

```sh
free | awk '/Mem/ { percent = $4 / $2 * 100.0; printf "%0.0f\n", percent; }'
```

Comment: or `free | awk '/Mem/{printf("%d\n", $4/$2*100)}'`

Answer (score 2):

1. Use awk /pattern/ to select the correct row.
2. Convert to integer to get rid of decimal points.

Code:

```
free | awk '/Mem/ { print int(100 * $4 / $2) }'
```